# CPAN error. How can I fix this?

Tags: json, perl, cygwin, cpan

This is driving me crazy- if you can be of assistance, I'd be much obliged.  I am running Cygwin on Windows 7.

I have been attempting to write a Perl script to obtain and work with some JSON information.  However, my `cpan` will not install some packages properly.  If I try to execute

```
install CPAN
```

or

```
install JSON
```

It seems to be going well for a while, but then I get an error message over and over again:

```
 0 [main] perl 3288 child_copy: loaded dll data write copy failed, 0x740D1000..0x740D27F0, done 0, windows pid 6600, Win32 error 487
```

Some people suggested executing `ash` from the DOS command prompt, and using `rebaseall`.  I tried this, and `dash`, to no avail.  The install still hangs, and when I start up `cpan` it displays

```
There seems to be running another CPAN process (pid 3764).  Contacting...
Other job not responding. Shall I overwrite the lockfile '/home/me/.cpan/.lock'? (Y/n) [y] y
```

I have `gcc` and as many other possible dependencies installed as many online have suggested in my search for help.  If you have any leads, I'd be most obliged.  Thank you.

Comment: why are you not installing perl on Windows 7 directly, rather than cygwin?

Comment: I have been attempting to upgrade my CPAN version and install a library for use of JSON in Perl scripts that I will use from the Cygwin command line (need access to constructs such as pipes and other *nix-ey things).  I can't access cpan from my DOS cmd prompt.

Answer (score 1):

i had issues installing pretty much any cpan module - same 'cant move' error!!

just disabled McAfee and all resolved.

Check and disable your AV.

Answer (score 0):

Re-run the cygwin installer to add the needed packages.

Comment: Is there any way to tell which dependencies cpan needs to function properly?  I have installed everything that people have suggested- make, gcc, etc.  Thanks!

Comment: Update:  I reinstalled Cygwin taking care to include `gcc-4`, which appears to be the missing compiler used to compile the makefiles, and now `cpan` seems to be getting along better with attempt to `install JSON` and `install JSON::XS`, but if I try `install CPAN` I get a long error message.  `Catching error: "Couldn't move /home/my name/.cpan/build/tmp-6112/CPAN-1.9800/distroprefs to /home/my name/.cpan/build/CPAN-1.9800-hbU14T/distroprefs: Is a directory at /usr/lib/perl5/5.10/CPAN ... ` etc.

Comment: Strange. If it is having trouble moving files it is most likely a permissions issue. Make sure you are running your install as root. If problems persist try _chmod_ on the directories in question.